# Send an array of variable instead of a single variable, over html button

Tags: php

I would like to send 2 variables on a click of a button
My Code so far is that:

HTML:

```
            <?php                   

              while ($Case=mysql_fetch_assoc($records)) {

                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$Case['SubmissionID']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$Case['AppID']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".getFullNameApp($Case['AppID'])."</td>";
                echo "<td>".getCourseName($Case['SubmissionCourseID'])."</td>";
                echo "<td>".getDepartmentName($Case['SubmissionCourseID'])."</td>";
                echo "<td>".DateFormat($Case['Date'])."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$Case['SubmissionStatus']."</td>";
                if ($Case['SubmissionStatus'] == 'Draft') {
                  echo "<form action='ApplicantApplyDetails.php' method='POST'>";
                  echo "<td><button type='submit' class='btn btn-success btn-xs' name='modifybtn' value='".array($Case['SubmissionID'], $Case['SubmissionCourseID'])."'>Modify</button></td>";
                }
                else {
                  echo "<td><button type='submit' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs disabled' disabled='disabled' name='modifybtndis' value=''>Modify</button></td>";
                }
                echo "</form>";         
                echo "</tr>";
              }

              mysql_close();
            ?>
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['modifybtn'])) {

$SubmissionID =$_POST['modifybtn'][0];
$CourseID = $_POST['modifybtn'][1];
echo $CourseID;
}
```

And then get those variables for further processing. Is that possible? I've done single ones but no arrays. My code is not working. The problem I think is in the HTML part,  but I have no idea how to fix it. Any hints?

Comment: what does `var_dump($_POST['modifybtn'])` looks like? start from there, or just follow Xorifelse answer.

Comment: There are some ways to pass two variables to php script, but i think it is not possible to pass an array. You can pass as a string with delimeter and split on a server, convert to a json and send to a server, create a formData object and add values to it and send to a server, use input hidden fields with values and submit a form in a standard way... Hopefully i gave you an idea.

Comment: Change name='modifybtn' to name='modifybtn[]' php will pick up that it an array that you are posting.

Comment: @jeff True, but this is a button, not a checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question; You can convert an array to a string:

```
$value = json_encode([$Case['SubmissionID'], $Case['SubmissionCourseID']]);
echo "<td><button type='submit' class='btn btn-success btn-xs' name='modifybtn' value='".$value."'>Modify</button></td>";
```

And covert the string back to the array when reading.

```
var_dump(json_decode($_POST['modifybtn'], true));
```

---

However there is also the option to submit a hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="courseid" value="<?= $Case['SubmissionCourseID']>">
```

And just use:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

Comment: The hidden field did the job..Very smart..Thanks Xorifelse