# Variable not working inside If statement

Tags: php

As I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41454781/send-an-array-of-variable-instead-of-a-single-variable-over-html-button/41454903#41454903), I managed to get 2 variable that I would like to use for further processing. Unfortunatly, I can't use is inside that if statement.

```
if (isset($_POST['modifybtn'])) { //Now we have our variables all set
    $SubmissionID = $_POST['modifybtn'];
    $CourseID = $_POST['courseid'];
    }
//We do some irrelevant stuff here.... and then

echo $CourseID; //Works
if (isset($_POST['savebtn'])) {
        echo $CourseID; //Not Working

    saveData($AppID, $CourseID);
    header("Location: applicantCase.php");
}
if (isset($_POST['nextbtn'])) {
    saveData($AppID, $CourseID);
    header("Location: ApplicantApplyEducation.php");
}
```

Why is that happening, one line before was working?

[image]

Comment: Do you manage to notice the echoed text just before redirection? Or do you expect to see the `$CourseID`s on `applicantCase.php`?

Comment: either `$_POST['savebtn']` is not set or 'irrelevant stuff' is rellevent

Comment: you set these value when $_POST['modifybtn'] is setted. but access these value when $_POST['savebtn'] is setted.

Comment: "irrelevant stuff " is the saveData function which it needs $CourseID to work. I dont expect $CourseID to applicantCase.php, It should do the job in this file and then redirect.

Comment: I have added a gif to see those buttons in action. If you notice At the end I have to rows (Applications) cause I can do the verification without $CourseID

Comment: if `$_POST['savebtn']` was set, you should get a nice error for output before header. of course you have full error checking and display on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, You can define outside the if condition.

```
 $SubmissionID = "";
 $CourseID = "";
if (isset($_POST['modifybtn'])) { //Now we have our variables all set
    $SubmissionID = $_POST['modifybtn'];
    $CourseID = $_POST['courseid'];
    }
//We do some irrelevant stuff here.... and then

echo $CourseID; //Works
if (isset($_POST['savebtn'])) {
        echo $CourseID; //Now it will Working

    saveData($AppID, $CourseID);
    header("Location: applicantCase.php");
}
if (isset($_POST['nextbtn'])) {
    saveData($AppID, $CourseID); // Now it will work
    header("Location: ApplicantApplyEducation.php");
}
```